# didTapMarker in Google Sdk not working

Tags: swift, google-maps

hi i added marker with latitude and longitude in map in ViewdidLoad and I want when user tap in marker load a xib in view in the first my function not work I want when user tap in marker print "Taped"!!
my class :

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    var ShopsInMap:[ObjectShop] = []
  var gmsMap = GMSMapView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gmsMap.delegate = self
        setMarker()
    }
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.gmsMap.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

and I use this function to add marker :

```
func setMarker(){
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:35.6892 , longitude: 51.3890, zoom: 10.0)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)

        view = mapView
        for shopvalue in ShopsInMap{
            if (shopvalue.lat != ""){
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                print("lat : \(Double(shopvalue.lat)!) lng is : \(Double(shopvalue.lng)!)")
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(shopvalue.lat)!, longitude: Double(shopvalue.lng)!)
                marker.title = "\(shopvalue.address) \n \(shopvalue.name)"
                marker.snippet = shopvalue.name
                marker.map = mapView
            }
        }
    }
```

and my extension is :

```
extension MapViewController :GMSMapViewDelegate{
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print("marker tap : \(marker.title)")
        return false
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print("taped is : \(coordinate.latitude)")
    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {

    }
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
        let coustome = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomeWindowsInfo", owner: self, options: nil) as! CustomeWindowsInfo
        coustome.test.text = marker.title
        print("taped ifno : \(marker.title)")
    }
}
```

I read all of question in stack overflow but I can use this function!!
thank for help me

Comment: did you add another mapView in storyboard?

Comment: I don't see where you add your mapView in ViewController.view or where you set a frame != CGRectZero

Comment: I do not understand :(

Comment: That's because of if (shopvalue.lat != ""){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the map in your viewController.view and adjust the frame

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    var ShopsInMap:[ObjectShop] = []
    var gmsMap = GMSMapView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubView(gmsMap)
        gmsMap.delegate = self
        setMarker()
    }

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.gmsMap.frame = self.view.bounds
}


func setMarker(){
        for shopvalue in ShopsInMap{
            if (shopvalue.lat != ""){
                let marker = GMSMarker()
                print("lat : \(Double(shopvalue.lat)!) lng is : \(Double(shopvalue.lng)!)")
                marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(shopvalue.lat)!, longitude: Double(shopvalue.lng)!)
                marker.title = "\(shopvalue.address) \n \(shopvalue.name)"
                marker.snippet = shopvalue.name
                marker.map = self.gmsMap
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: add this method but function didTap Marker not working

Comment: can you update your question with your current code? @AmirFarahani

Comment: in my storyboard set class of view to GMSMapView?

Comment: you have missed this line in viewDidLoad    `self.view.addSubView(gmsMap)`please replace your viewDidLoad with my implementation @AmirFarahani

Comment: check my updated answer, you must to replace your setMarker method too, @AmirFarahani let me know if works as should be